# Simple webservice with node-soap

Tags: node.js, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am trying to implement a simple web service using SOAP using Node Js and node-soap, but the client side seems to have problems using the server.

```
assert.js:92
  throw new assert.AssertionError({
        ^
AssertionError: invalid message definition for document style binding
```

My wsdl file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions name="wscalc1"
                  targetNamespace="http://localhost:8000/wscalc1"
                  xmlns="http://localhost:8000/wscalc1"
                  xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
                  xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/"
                  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                  xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/">

  <wsdl:message name="sumarRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="a" type="xs:string"></wsdl:part>
    <wsdl:part name="b" type="xs:string"></wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>

  <wsdl:message name="multiplicarRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="a" type="xs:string"></wsdl:part>
    <wsdl:part name="b" type="xs:string"></wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>

  <wsdl:message name="multiplicarResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="res" type="xs:string"></wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>

  <wsdl:message name="sumarResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="res" type="xs:string"></wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>


  <wsdl:portType name="calcP">
    <wsdl:operation name="sumar">
      <wsdl:input message="sumarRequest"></wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output message="sumarResponse"></wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>

    <wsdl:operation name="multiplicar">
      <wsdl:input message="multiplicarRequest"></wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output message="multiplicarResponse"></wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>

  <wsdl:binding name="calcB" type="calcP">
    <soap:binding style="document" 
                  transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>

    <wsdl:operation name="sumar">
      <soap:operation soapAction="sumar"/>
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal" 
                   encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal" 
                   encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>

    <wsdl:operation name="multiplicar">
      <soap:operation soapAction="multiplicar"/>
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal" 
                   encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal" 
                   encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>

  <wsdl:service name="ws">
    <wsdl:port name="calc" binding="calcB">
      <soap:address location="http://localhost:8000/wscalc1"/>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

server.js

```
var soap = require('soap');
var http = require('http');

var service = {
    ws: {
        calc: {
            sumar : function(args) {
                var n = args.a + args.b;
                return { res : n };
            },

            multiplicar : function(args) {
                var n = args.a * args.b;
                return { res : n }
            }
        }
    }
}

var xml = require('fs').readFileSync('wscalc1.wsdl', 'utf8'),

server = http.createServer(function(request,response) {
    response.end("404: Not Found: "+request.url)
});

server.listen(8000);
soap.listen(server, '/wscalc1', service, xml);
```

client.js

```
var soap = require('soap');
var url = 'http://localhost:8000/wscalc1?wsdl';
soap.createClient(url, function(err, client) {

    if (err) throw err;


    console.log(client.describe().ws.calc);

    client.multiplicar({"a":"1","b":"2"},function(err,res){
        if (err) throw err;

        console.log(res);
    });
});
```

with that code the output is:

```
{ sumar: 
   { input: { a1: 'Request', b1: 'Request' },
     output: { res: 'Response' } },
  multiplicar: 
   { input: { a2: 'Request', b2: 'Request' },
     output: { res: 'Response' } } }

assert.js:92
  throw new assert.AssertionError({
        ^
AssertionError: invalid message definition for document style binding
```

any help will be really appreciated

Answer (score 6):

As user672320 pointed out the reason client.js failed was because the format of the wsdl used was 'RPC/literal' but the style was set as 'document' rather than RPC.

In fact any one of five formats can be used for wsdl, each has a diferent format.

See [Which style of WSDL should I use?](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/ws-whichwsdl/) for a discussion of which style to use.

Also, the example given is not complete.

See below for expanded version:

wsdl file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions name="wscalc1" targetNamespace="http://localhost:8000/wscalc1" xmlns="http://localhost:8000/wscalc1" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <wsdl:message name="sumarRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="a" type="xs:string"/>
    <wsdl:part name="b" type="xs:string"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="multiplicarRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="a" type="xs:string"/>
    <wsdl:part name="b" type="xs:string"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="multiplicarResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="mulres" type="xs:string"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="sumarResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="sumres" type="xs:string"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="calcP">
    <wsdl:operation name="sumar">
      <wsdl:input message="sumarRequest"/>
      <wsdl:output message="sumarResponse"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="multiplicar">
      <wsdl:input message="multiplicarRequest"/>
      <wsdl:output message="multiplicarResponse"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding name="calcB" type="calcP">
    <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="sumar">
      <soap:operation soapAction="sumar"/>
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="multiplicar">
      <soap:operation soapAction="multiplicar"/>
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="ws">
    <wsdl:port binding="calcB" name="calc">
      <soap:address location="http://localhost:8001/wscalc1"/>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

server.js:

```
/*jslint node: true */
"use strict";

var soap = require('soap');
var http = require('http');

var service = {
    ws: {
        calc: {
            sumar : function(args) {
                var n = 1*args.a + 1*args.b;
                return { sumres : n };
            },

            multiplicar : function(args) {
                var n = args.a * args.b;
                return { mulres : n };
            }
        }
    }
};

var xml = require('fs').readFileSync('wscalc1.wsdl', 'utf8');

var server = http.createServer(function(request,response) {
    response.end("404: Not Found: "+request.url);
});

server.listen(8001);
soap.listen(server, '/wscalc1', service, xml);
```

client.js:

```
var soap = require('soap');
var url = 'http://localhost:8001/wscalc1?wsdl';

soap.createClient(url, function(err, client) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(client.describe().ws.calc);
    client.multiplicar({a: 4,b: 3},function(err,res){
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(res);
    });
    client.sumar({a: 4,b: 3},function(err,res){
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(res);
    });
});
```

with that the code output is:

```
   { sumar:
   { input: { a: 'xs:string', b: 'xs:string' },
     output: { sumres: 'xs:string' } },
  multiplicar:
   { input: { a: 'xs:string', b: 'xs:string' },
     output: { mulres: 'xs:string' } } }
   { mulres: '12' }
   { sumres: '7' }
```

Comment: Any idea why is the namespace is undefined, when I try this example using a soap call?

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" >
    <soap:Body>
        <undefined:multiplicarResponse>
            <undefined:mulres>6</undefined:mulres>
        </undefined:multiplicarResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

Answer (score 1):

in the wsdl file what i change is the style from document to rpc trying to get antoher response using the client.js

What i receive is this output.

```
{ sumar: 
   { input: { a: 'xs:string', b: 'xs:string' },
     output: { res: 'xs:string' } },
  multiplicar: 
   { input: { a: 'xs:string', b: 'xs:string' },
     output: { res: 'xs:string' } } }
{ res: '2' }
```